# 'Outlet' is not defined in react-router v6.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How `Outlet` should be defined in `react-router` v6.4.

Here is my code

```
function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: [Here is the better e.g. from docs](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/basic?file=src%2FApp.tsx) ... [docs for ref](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet)

Comment: Post is unclear. What exactly is the issue? What is the *question*?

Answer (score 0):

Import the values from the router and use the following structure

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

<BrowserRouter>
   <HeaderSignIn />
   <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<HomePageSignIn />} />
      <Route path="/sign-in" element={<SigIn />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LogIn />} />
      <Route path="/admin_login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/explore" element={<Explore />} />
      <Route path="/shop" element={<ShopView />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="/job" element={<PleaseLogIn />} />
      <Route path="/new-shop-item" element={<PleaseLogIn />} />
      <Route path="/new-shop" element={<PleaseLogIn />} />
   </Routes>
   <Footer />
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Follow the ReactRouter Documentation for more information**

Comment: I guess the answer is not exactly related to the Q asked